# Calling OnDraw in MFC SDI application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to make a MFC SDI application in VC++ to draw different shapes on click of the respective button. We have written our code inside the OnDraw() function. But Ondraw gets automatically called on running the application. We want it to be called only on the onclick of respective button. How do we proceed..?

Answer (score 1):

1. When a shape button is clicked set a member variable that remembers what you want to draw.
2. Call Invalidate. This will cause OnDraw to be called by the framework.
3. In OnDraw check the member variable and draw the shape.

You must permit OnDraw to draw every time it is called by the framework. That is how the window image is restored after being uncovered, unminimized, resized, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cant prevent that OnDraw is only called when you press a button.

OnDraw in a view is called when WM_PAINT arrives and asks the window to repaint itself. Not executing OnDraw would cause nothing to be drawn at all.

OnDraw is also called when your application is minimized and maximized again, or when the size of the window changes.

Also I can not think about a scenario, where I want drawing only when a button is pressed. You need to be more precise. here.

Comment: i want to display different shapes based on mouse click. For example if a user clicks on square a square should be drawn. So the code to draw  that is written in onDraw. So how to draw only that particular shape on click.?

Comment: You should make a difference between drawing and creating. In you view you create a shape. Afterwards you must draw it. Drawing in doneon OnDraw. Creation is usually done inside  a command handler.

Answer (score 0):

OnDraw, as xMRi said, is called by the framework ... but if you want to draw something only when you click on a button, why don't you create a member variable, setup when you click the button, and get count when OnDraw is executed ?

```
void CYourAppView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    // MFC code
    if(m_bButtonWasClicked)
    {
        // draw what ever you want
    }
}
```